# Can I place string file from res/values/string.xml to remote host server and read it from there

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

I want to move string.xml from my Android app res/values/ folder to my website.

http://example.com/string.xml

It will be easier for me to edit it from there, than always update app to google play.

Is that possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <string name="app_name">MyRadio</string>
    <string name="version">1.0</string>  


<string-array name="station_names">
        <item>NRG radio</item>              

<string-array name="station_urls">
        <item>rtmp://radiostation.com/radiomp3</item>

<string-array name="station_detail">
        <item>Radio detail</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are certainly welcome to host files on your Web server. You are certainly welcome to download those files yourself, within your app, to your users' devices. However:

- You need to download the files
- You need to know when to download the files, based on when they might change
- You will need to parse the files, as they will no longer be string resources
- You will need to adapt your code to use the parsed results, rather than the string resources that you are currently using

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I am a very new to android and eclipse so i thing those thing will be quite difficult for me to do. BTW do you have some video tutorials about those thing what should i search  on youtube  "parsing"

Comment: Normally, strings.xml stores things that won't be modified so often, like labels, messages, etc. From your question, I think what you need are webservices (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). Think about your app needs in terms of services, like "I need the list of restaurants nearby" or "Give my user's expendables from July".

As @CommonsWare noted in his answare, you will to parse your "strings" (the services' answers). Hopefully, there are some approaches you can follow, like JSON http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: Bolhoso thanks. In my string I have some urls that often can be changed radio stations. If a need to delete or add new station it will be easier to edit xml on my server than update  hole application to google, Sorry my english. I hope I explained in some way.